# Changing ISODate into String Date ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express, isodate

How i change my value "created_at" attribute on array map.

this is my object

```
{ _id: 59661cba54481612500d3043,
  author_id: 595e51e0f14cff12e896ead7,
  updated_at: 2017-07-12T13:07:52.913Z,
  created_at: 2017-12-06T17:00:00.000Z,
  trash: false,
  tag: [ 595e51e0f14cff12e896ead9, 595e51e0f14cff12e896ead3 ],
  category: [ 595e51e0f14cff12e896ead9, 595e51e0f14cff12e896ead3 ],
  title: 'test2' }
```

i want change the value created_at into simple date like this = "13-07-2017"

this is my code

```
function article(req, res) {
postArticle.find({}, function(err, articles) {
    articles.map(function(article) {
        var dateCreate = new Date(article.created_at);
        var newDate = dateCreate.getDate()+'-' +(dateCreate.getMonth()+1)+'-' +dateCreate.getFullYear();
        article.created_at = newDate;
        console.log(dateCreate);
        console.log(newDate)
        console.log(article)
    });

    // res.render('admin/article/index', {title: 'Article Posts', posts: article})
    // res.json({title: 'article', posts: article})
    // console.log(article)
})}
```

but my code doesn't work for changing :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written a method in my project to do this, You can use this code to change the format of date.

```
function article(req, res) {
postArticle.find({}, function(err, articles) {
    articles.map(function(article) {
        var dateCreate = formatDate(article.created_at);
        var newDate = formatDate(new Date());
        article.created_at = newDate;
        console.log(dateCreate);
        console.log(newDate)
        console.log(article)
    });

    // res.render('admin/article/index', {title: 'Article Posts', posts: article})
    // res.json({title: 'article', posts: article})
    // console.log(article)
})}
```

**Method to format date:**

```
var formatDate = function (date) {
    var myDate = new Date(date);

    var y = myDate.getFullYear(),
        m = myDate.getMonth() + 1, // january is month 0 in javascript
        d = myDate.getDate();

    // Get the DD-MM-YYYY format
    return formatDigit(d) + "-" + formatDigit(m) + "-" + y;
}
```

This method will return Month or Day in two digit. Ex. if `formatDigit(4) // 04`

```
    /**
     * Format a month or day in two digit.
     */
    var formatDigit = function (val) {
        var str = val.toString();
        return (str.length < 2) ? "0" + str : str
    };
```

Hope it will work for you.